# Copy data from local production SQL Server database to remote read only SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, remote-server, log-shipping

I'll start by explaining what the current set up is and then go onto where it needs to be.

Currently we have a local SQL Server database for a CMS. The database is updated from other servers on site to update product information to display on the website, and CMS information is updated from an MVC application.

Moving forward we need to have a remote server with a SQL Server database that is an identical copy of the local database, this database will never be updated from the remote location.

The problem arises when attempting to design a method to sync the data from the local database to the remote server with no downtime on either end. I know SQL Server Enterprise has features that would help in this case, but we do not have a licence for it at this time.

The best idea we have come up with is to log ship to the remote server, create a restore from database that is receiving the logs being shipped and then update the website's `web.config` to point to the newly restored database. This could work, but seems overly complicated and we have an issue of an ever changing database name.

If any one could think of a better/simpler solution or a way to make the current idea better it would be much appreciated.

If anything is not clear or more info is needed let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logshipping solution fits your needs. After a one-time setup proces, the logs would be continually shipped from the local db to the remote db. Keeping the remote perfectly in sync with the local one, providing you with the readonly copy.

Logshipping is available in all editions, besides Express.

There would be no need for a continuous restore process.

You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895393%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: One issue is that the secondary database will kick all the users off every time it executes the restore job. The job should run quickly if you run it with reasonable frequency, and your code could be written such that it will simply reconnect and retry if the connection disappears while a SELECT is in progress.